# How to configure a static IP address in android Device programmatically

Tags: java, android, ip, router

The wireless connection of our Android Device will be automatically connecting to the Wireless Access Point or Router in normal circumstances. In such cases, the IP settings will be assigned by the Router during the setup phase of your wireless connection. The IP addresses will be different each time you are connecting to the wireless network.

**In my case I want static IP for connecting multiple devices over wifi.**

**How can I set static IP in android using programming. when i connect same WiFi router multiple time**